# Packetfence unable to configure due to multiple IPs on same network

Tags: networking, debian, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, vlan

I'm trying to install PacketFence on a virtual machine, and have dedicated 8 IPs to the server.

They all are static on eth1:0 -> eth1:7, so not eth1, eth2, etc.

When trying to configure vlans for "normal", "registration" etc. in Packetfence I get an error saying they need to be on different networks.

Can't I install Packetfence without physically separate networks?

Answer (score 0):

The static routes use the same primary IP assigned to the device, so it might be a good idea to provision a portable subnet for your purpose.

Nevertheless, you could submit a ticket to SoftLayer, so that they might provide you further assistance.